# java аннотации обязательные поля

Tags: java, аннотации

Пытаюсь сделать свою аннотацию с параметрами

```
@Qualifier
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface TestInterface {
    public String name();
    public String value();
}
```

Помечаю ей поле в другом классе:

```
public class Test{
    @TestInterface (name = "s2",value = "s2")
    private String ss; }
```

И все бы хорошо, но если я убираю параметры, то выдается ошибка `missing default values for elements name value`

```
public class Test{
    @TestInterface
    private String ss; }
```

Обычно во фреймворках я могу использовать как аннотации без параметров, так и указывать их. Как это реализовано? Есть некие  *default values* или как то иначе настроено?

Иными словами как сделать так, что бы можно было использовать аннотацию с и без параметров?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У аннотаций должны быть заданы значения по умолчанию

```
public @interface TestInterface {
    public String name() default "";
    public String value() default "";
}
```